# What syntax construct should be used for rulebook quotes?

Tags: discussion

When quoting the rules of a game, there are two obvious options:

> Block quotes

and

```
code blocks
```

Each one has problems.

Block quotes are much more limited in terms of layout.  You can't have custom indentation or arbitrary spacing.

```
The following has no block quote equivalent:
    mmmmm    mmmmm    mmmmm
    nnnnn    nnnnn    nnnnn
```

The fanciest thing you can do in block quotes is bullets:

> This is the closest block quote equivalent to the above:
>
> - mmmmm mmmmm mmmmm
> - nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn

Meanwhile, code blocks don't look as good on mobile and don't support bold or italics.  Are there general guidelines for when to use each (if ever)?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [Can we agree on a standard format for MTG rules quotes?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1242/6692)

Comment: @Rainbolt I found that question; it appeared to be entirely about formatting the contents of the quote blocks, not about quote blocks vs code blocks

Comment: You misintepreted the other question. The question was *"Can we agree on a format for rules quotes?"*, not *"Assuming that we all agree that rules quotes go in quote blocks, can we also agree on the remainder of the format?"*

Answer (score 14):

Any time you're quoting more than one line of someone else's text, you should use a block quote. If you really need custom indentation, you can represent that part of the quotation as a code block within a block quote:

> This is a code block in a block quote:
>
> ```
>     mmmmm   mmmmm   mmmmm
>     nnnnn   nnnnn   nnnnn
> ```
>
> With bullet points afterward:
>
> - Bullet 1
> - Bullet 2

On this site, you should only use code blocks when the specific indentation and spacing are essential (such as with tables or ASCII art), or when actually writing code.

Comment: Pretty much this. The kind of formatting you should use should always match the type of text you are formatting so that things like screen readers can properly parse the text.